# Problem with flex-mojos

Tags: maven, flex-mojos

If I try the getting-started on http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/getting-started.html I get some errors. Can somebody help me out? I'm new to maven, but since it's a getting-started, I was hopin' everything would go smooth...not.

Errors:

```
Missing:
----------
1) net.sf.saxon:saxon-dom:jar:9.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=net.sf.saxon -DartifactId=saxon-dom -Dv
ersion=9.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:

      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=net.sf.saxon -DartifactId=saxon-dom -Dver
sion=9.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:3.4.2
        2) net.sf.saxon:saxon-dom:jar:9.0

2) org.graniteds:granite-generator-share:jar:2.0.0.GA

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.graniteds -DartifactId=granite-gene
rator-share -Dversion=2.0.0.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:

      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.graniteds -DartifactId=granite-genera
tor-share -Dversion=2.0.0.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -D
repositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:3.4.2
        2) org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-generator-graniteds-2.0.0:jar:3.4.2
        3) org.graniteds:granite-generator-share:jar:2.0.0.GA

3) org.jvnet:animal-sniffer-annotation:jar:1.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.jvnet -DartifactId=animal-sniffer-a
nnotation -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:

      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.jvnet -DartifactId=animal-sniffer-ann
otation -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -Dreposit
oryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:3.4.2
        2) org.jvnet:animal-sniffer-annotation:jar:1.0

----------
3 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact:
  org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:3.4.2

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These dependencies are not available in the repository that is being used (central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)). For instance, the Saxon-dom dependency only has a 8.7 version and not a 9.0 as you require. http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/saxon/saxon-dom/

To solve this, you need to add an extra repository to the pom that does have these dependencies.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>flex-mojos-repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```